# What is meant by "homogenous problem" exactly?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let us look at an entirely linear problem with operator $L$.

For an algebraic equation $Lu=0$ is a homogenous equation.

If $L$ is a differential operator (PDE or ODE) it has to be supplemented with a linear combination of boundary conditions over an interval, thus another operator $R$ such that $Rv=b$. Here $v$ is a mixed vector ike a Robin type bounday condition. What is meant by "homogenous problem" then.

Is it simply $Lu =0$ or the former coupled with $Rv =0$? Please elaborate about the linear independence of the mixed type of boundary conditions or suggest a resource?

Comment: Homogeneous $\implies Lu = 0$, inhomogeneous/non-homogeneous $\implies Lu = f$ for some $f \ne 0$ only.

Comment: I would refer you to "Introduction to Perturbations Techniques" by A.H. Nayfeh, Pg 401, Chap 15- Solavability Conditions

Comment: Anybody..I hoped the question would be easy

Comment: @ Ricky I answered this for you the other day. You referred me to a book that said exactly the same thing as I did?

Comment: In the same chapter if one looks closely a distinction is being made in a subtle manner between a homogenous "equation" vs a homogenous "problem". In the same reference the following problem shows why not all particular solutions are admissible in face of boundary conditions.  Consider $y'' + \pi^2y=0; y(0)=y(1)=0$ vs $y'' + \pi^2y=\pi sin(\pi x); y(0)=\beta_1, y(1)=\beta_2$(Page 401).  The confusion stemmed for me since the rest of the book doesn't give any heed to this problem except in this last chapter. Hitherto I had opined the same as you.